# How Can I set the ng-disabled value of a button based on the original value of a model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am attempting to disable a button which is next to a checkbox, but only if the underlying model of the checkbox is different from the original value. Pristine on it's own doesn't work because technically the form has been changed. My solution was to grab the original value and toggle the pristine value of the form based on whether current value is equal to that value.

I'm assuming there is a better way which I am unaware of.

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-form="form">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-click="toggle(form)" ng-model="foo.bar">{{ foo.bar }}
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$pristine" ng-click="save(form)">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){

  //catch when scope is first set
  $scope.$watch("foo", function(curr, prev){
    if(curr && !prev)
      $scope.original = curr.bar;

  });

  //assume this is being set by some other scope
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.foo = {
      bar: true
    };
  }, 500);

  $scope.toggle = function(form){
    if($scope.original == $scope.foo.bar)
      form.$setPristine();
    console.log(form.$pristine);
  };

  $scope.save = function(form){
     $scope.original = $scope.foo.bar;
    form.$setPristine();
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you use $pristine, or a $watch.

Just store the original value in a scope variable when the controller is instantiated, and use

```
ng-disabled="foo.bar != original"
```